# SQL synchronized issue using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a piece of code which is running in C# using backgroundworker communicating with the SQL server (in VM).

ex.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CreateSQLTable();

    // xxx methods not related to SQL

    DeleteSQLTable();
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

In CreateSQLTable function I only have creating the SQL table and sending SQL command without getting any return value back and the timeout is setting up longer like 120s ensure the SQL server fully runs the command. In the RunWorkerComplete I have RunworkerAsync in order to loop this task.

Problems:

1. Duplicate table keep creating in the database from the CreateSQLTable(), its odd that it suppose to only create one however in my database keep showing more even I have the delete function following.

2.*which is critical* Exception for Object not found when deleting the table which crash the application. My best guess is when deleting the table it can not find the created table from before.

From my understanding that although call the backgroundworker should be async, but the contents running inside of the backgroundworker is sync. So such problem should not appear.

Another sub question wondering might be the cause of the problem is that, at the SQL database part, is it take the command then run within the timeout value? It it might get interrupted once the timeout value reached? Or is it because the background worker and the UI are written in different class (due to the MVC)?

Could anyone have experience for multithreading explain this for me please? Much appreciated :)

Comment: 120 seconds for a simple `CREATE TABLE` statement sounds like a _huge_ code design/system architecture issue.

Comment: I doubt your problem is related to the worker, try the code in (per example) a button click and check if it has the same behavior (and debug the real problem).

Comment: If any of the `//xxx methods not related to SQL` hit an exception, then depending on your exception handling logic, you might exit the method early and the table might not get deleted.  You may want to implement a `try-catch-finally` where the table is deleted (if it exists) in the `finally` statement.

Comment: @ElementalPete Try and catch already applied for the whole thing.

Comment: @Gusman It was running fine in local machine however running in VM will have the problems above :( and it is trigger by button click

Comment: Then you have some problem in your VM setup, may be the network configuration?

Comment: My point was that if you create a table, and then do something that throws an exception, and then catch that exception, you will never make it to the point in the code where the table is deleted.  That would be exactly why you would need to move `DeleteSQLTable()` to the finally block - and don't assume that it exists, because depending on where the exception happened, it may not...

Comment: @Gusman the odd thing is that if i set up delay before create table and delete table that the function works fine. do you mind explain why its related the network config on VM? lantency too long?

Comment: I'm not affirming it's a problem with network, just a guess, but VM machines are very prone to misconfigure the net properties, if you have a big latency or packet loss then it may cause problems